# Merging time series in mathematica efficiently

Tags: dataset, wolfram-mathematica, time-series

what i am trying to accomplish seems ordinary enough for there to be an efficient solution.

I am using [mathematica](/questions/tagged/mathematica) and i have a number of different [timeseries](/questions/tagged/timeseries) of the type {{date1, value1},{date1, value1}...} - the sort you could pass to DateListPlot.

However, the problem is that these [datasets](/questions/tagged/datasets) only partially overlap (some may have data from 95-2004, some from 1999 to 2011 and so on)

Now what I would love to be able to do is to merge these into one big list with a common timeline that is the Union[] of all the dates available. Then there would be arrays for the values, but with zeros where there is no data.

Is there an efficient way to accomplish this? I have hundreds of these timeseries and making something that loops the whole thing is probably not very efficient (and even quite tedious to make)

any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you give example input and output?

Comment: Given that Mathematica doesn't need to "pad" data sets to plot them on the same chart, do you really need this? Or are you going to export it to something like Excel, where the NaN equivalents are necessary?

Comment: @Verbeia but it depends on what "this" is that is needed, does it not? should one create the missing dates and add them with 0 as the data? create some of the missing dates? are some dates supplied but with no data and, if yes, in which form? it would help to know!

Comment: @acl, yes, but I tried to answer anyway :-)

Answer (score 2):

For instance,

```
ClearAll[l1, l2];
l1 = {{date1, value1}, {date1, value2}, {date2, value3}, {date4, value4}}
l2 = {{date3, value5}, {date4, value5}, {date1, value6}}
```

then

```
DeleteDuplicates[Union[l1, l2], #1[[1]] \[Equal] #2[[1]] &]
```

yields `{{date1, value1}, {date2, value3}, {date3, value5}, {date4, value4}}`. This means that if you have two data points for the same date, and they are different, one will be lost. It's not clear (to me) if this is what you need or not, so perhaps you could add more detail.

On the other hand, this

```
Transpose[{DeleteDuplicates[Last@Last@Reap@Scan[Sow[#[[1]]] &, Union[l1, l2]]],
 Last@Reap[Scan[Sow[#[[2]], #[[1]]] &, Union[l1, l2]]]}]
```

eliminates duplicate headers and collects the values under each header thus:

```
{{date1, {value1, value2, value6}}, 
 {date2, {value3}}, 
 {date3, {value5}}, 
 {date4, {value4, value5}}}
```

(ie, it collects all values for each date).

Some examples of what you want would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want

```
l1 = {{date1, value1}, {date1, value2}, {date2, value3}, {date4, value4}}
l2 = {{date3, value5}, {date4, value5}, {date5, value6}}
```

To become

```
l1 = {{date1, value1}, {date1, value2}, 
     {date2, value3}, {date3, 0}, {date4, value4}, {date5,0}}
l2 = {{date1, 0}, {date2, 0}, {date3, value5}, {date4, value5}, {date5, value6}}
```

If so, something like this might work:

```
If[MemberQ[l1[[All,1]],#],Cases[l1,{#,_}],{#,0}]& /@ Union[l1[[All,1]],l2[[All,2]] ]
```

Depending on how you want multiple data points on the same date in a given series to be treated, you might need to precede the  Cases[] function with Sequence @@ or First@, e.g.

```
If[MemberQ[l1[[All,1]],#],Sequence @@ Cases[l1,{#,_}],{#,0}]& /@   
  Union[l1[[All,1]],l2[[All,1]] ]
```

I'm home now, so this one has been checked for syntax errors :-)

Comment: but here this gives '{{{date1, value1}, {date1, value2}}, {{date2, value3}}, {{date4, value4}}, {value5, 0}, {value6, 0}}'. maybe there's a cut and paste error somewhere

Comment: That's because I'm an idiot. SHould have been  Union[l1[[All,1]],l2[[All,1]] ] not  Union[l1[[All,1]],l2[[All,2]] ] -- fixed now

Comment: Thanks guys. I ended up myself doing the solution that i took the union of all timelines. Saving that in let's say datevar i then used Mapthread in the following way

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I ended up myself doing the solution that i took the union of all timelines. Saving that in let's say daterange i then used Mapthread in the following way

```
daterange= Union[DatesOfFirstTimeseries,DatesOfSecondTimeseries];

NewVersionOfFirstTimeSeries = (daterange /. 
     MapThread[Rule, {DatesOfFirstTimeseries, ValuesOfFirstTimeseries}] /. 
    MapThread[
     Rule, {daterange, Table[Indeterminate, {Length[daterange]}]}]);

NewVersionOfSecondTimeSeries = (daterange /. 
     MapThread[Rule, {DatesOfSecondTimeseries, ValuesOfSecondTimeseries}] /. 
    MapThread[
     Rule, {daterange, Table[Indeterminate, {Length[daterange]}]}]);
```

tjis did what i need, but it really does hurt my aesthetic view of things.

Comment: it may be easier to understand what this is meant to do if you supply examples for `DatesOfFirstTimeseries` etc